# Why does calling `SSTORE` on a dynamic bytes value of length 32 always result in the value being equal to `0x000...080`?

Tags: solidity

Consider this snippet of Solidity (version ^0.8.9):

```
bytes32 key = bytes32(0);
bytes memory val = abi.encodePacked(bytes32(0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF));
bytes32 result;
assembly {
    sstore(key, val)
    result := sload(key)
}
// Expected: result = 0xFFF...FFF
// Actual: result = 0x000...080
result;
```

`result` is always equal to `0x000...080` regardless of the value of `val`. This is surprising to
me; I'd expect `result` to be equal to `val`.

Note that if `val` is of type `bytes32`, then this issue disappears, and `val` equals `result`.